# mySQL SELECT more than one

Tags: mysql

i have a table with colums section number like 1 , 2 , 3 etc and room number 1000, 2000, 3000, etc. Room # 2000 is being used by sections 2 and 3.

I want a SQL code to select the rooms that being shared by more than one section. 
Please note that I have another column called days (Sat, Sun, Mon..) and there are some rooms that are being used by same section more than once. For example room 2000 is used Mon, Tue. So using count() would not work.

I have tried it

```
SELECT 
    roomNumber
FROM

    section
having
    count(section_number) > 1
```

but that didn't work. Please help

P.S. : I am new to mySQL

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Select roomNumber from section group by roomNumber having count(roomNumber) > 1
```

Comment: i tried that but that show also other rooms that are being shared more than once by one section (for example, room # 1000 is being used by section number 1 at different times Sat. Sun. Mon...etc (another column called days))

Comment: can you try this "group by roomNumber, section" ... i.e both column parameter in group by

Comment: Thanks DECODE. I tried that. It returns the rooms used more than once by one section and more than one section and all I need is the rooms used by more than one section.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. You are missing the `group by` clause. Add that after your table declarations and before the having clause.

```
select   roomNumber
from     section
group by roomNumber
having   count(section_number) > 1;
```

You may to adjust if you need account for null values.